# correct HTTP response headers to cause 304s after content expiration

Tags: http, caching, http-headers

I'd like an HTTP response to expire 24 hours from now (meaning the browser won't make any requests for that URL until tomorrow). But, if the request is re-issued tomorrow after expiration, I want to make sure the browser will send the right request headers so that the server will send a 304 instead of forcing the client to re-download the whole response body if it hasn't changed on the server. And I'd like that 304 to also expire 24 hours later.

First, is this sccenario possible? Or do I have to choose between Expiration-style caching and 304-style caching, but not both?  If it is possible, what are the right response headers (both for the initial response and for the subsequent 304s) which will make it happen?

If as often happens, the answer varies based on browser type/version, then which headers work for which browsers-- and which browsers won't be able to do what I want at all?  I'm only interested in the most common browsers in use today (e.g. IE6+, FF3+, Chrome latest, Safari latest)?

Apologies if this answer has already been asked on SO-- I searched for a while and came up blank.

**CLARIFICATION**: I'm asking this question because I'm putting together an automated test suite to verify, regardless of server platform, that a web app is generating the correct HTTP headers to generate the client-caching behavior we want all our web apps to have.  So I'm not interested (at least for now) in how to configure Apache/IIS/PHP/Rails/Django/JSP/ASP.NET/etc. to generate the right headers. I simply want to know, at the HTTP layer only, what the right headers are.

**UPDATE:** I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187493/max-age-and-304-not-modified-processing) which answers part of my question. According to [RFC 2616 10.3.5](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5), it says, I should include an `Expires:` or `Cache-Control: max-age` headers to the 304s returned by the server. This is definitely the desired behavior.

What that question doesn't answer, however, is whether this RFC-compliant approach will work on existing popular browsers, especially IE6/7/8 which are the usual standards-compliance culprits, but also IE9, FF4+, latest Chrome, and latest Safari which our application also must support.  If any of those browsers don't behave as the RFC mandates, are there workarounds I can use?

Comment: Without knowing what webserver this realtes to and whether the content is generated by code or simply a static file served up by the server its impossible to answer.

Comment: In this case they will almost certainly be dynamic requests, but my question is server-platform-agnostic.  I'm just looking for the desired HTTP response headers to cause clients to cache as I'd like. I added a clarification to the end of my question to elaborate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Send an `ETAG` header so that the client may make a conditional HTTP request to revalidate a response after its freshness lifetime has expired.

Send a `Cache-Control: max-age` or `Expires` directive to specify when you want the resource to expire.

Avoid using a `Vary` header or any directive that forbids caching.

These directives will work in all popular browsers (IE6+, Firefox, Chrome) except for Safari on Windows, which alone lacks a persistent HTTP cache that works across multiple sessions.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/07/14/caching-improvements-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx explains what happens when you fail to provide proper caching headers.

Fiddler's Caching response inspector will help you understand how a given response will be cached.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [the `ETag` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag).

Comment: ETag alone isn't enough, as clients will still make a new HTTP request each time to check if the ETag is still current.  At least one additional header is needed to control content expiration to prevent making any requests for 24 hours before checking back for a new ETag.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks Justin! So I guess you'd need to use the `Expires` header along with `ETag`, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if Expires plus ETag will do the trick (and even if it does will it work across multiple browsers?).